# MySQL: create function that returns an array

Tags: mysql, arrays, function

CREATE Function getNearIds (myLocationLon double, myLocationLat double) RETURNS **WHAT**

I just want to return an array of integers, after a long search: some say use Group_concat to make the list as a comma separated list then use find_in_set when calling the function. this works ok but in HQL (Hibernate query language) it doesn't.

so I need a clear way for this function to return an array of integers, what if i want to return a list of items from items table, is this possible.

I think this is very simple to do in Oracle DB or even SQL server. why is it very tough in MySQL.

please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use a stored procedure instead? You could simply have it return a result set that had rows with just one column.

Stored functions can't do what you want to do - well, I suppose you could do that group concat thing but why bother? Create the stored procedure and have it return the ints you want.

Something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getNearIds 
     (myLocationLon double, myLocationLat double)
BEGIN
   # whatever your logic is to get the ids... 
   # e.g.,
   select id from locations where [whatever "near" means]
END
```

Comment: first of all thanks for your concern .  i agree with you a stored procedure yet i have to define an argument in the hear that is "OUT" so what data type will it have. in another words who would I the caller of the proc get these ids in your select statement . sorry I'm basicly an oracle developer who can newly to my sql to find interesting restrictions  yet a simpler database engine to easy the development.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but there's no "OUT" in this example - it's a proc that returns a result set - essentially a collection of rows that each have one column that is, presumably, of type int - though I guess those IDs could be anything, right?  It would depend upon your DB table, but I'm assuming the IDs are integers.  If you rephrase your question, maybe that will help me understand more what you mean.

Comment: Hey, This is interesting. You said ** it's a proc that returns a result set**.... can a proc return something. well this is really new to me please send me a sample on how to use your sample proc above. and thanks very much for this info

Comment: `CALL getNearIds (10.5, 10.6);` is the syntax.  Check out http://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql-stored-procedures.aspx for more info on stored procs.

Comment: @itsmatt, I need to call the procedure from php script. Then how I could get the array, that should be returned? Can you give me a snip of code?